# Access to localhost website with Iphone conected to iMac

Tags: php, html, macos, apache

I´m trying to test a website in my Iphone that I have running on my localhost on Mountain Lion.

First I created wireless from the mac called "webdev", then, with the Iphone I connected to it and the access to internet works, the problem is when I try to enter to my Mac localhost site it keeps loading with no result, also if I try to enter to the root: "http://webdev.local" I get a **Forbidden** error.

Any idea why I can´t connect with my Iphone to local sites on my mac?

Comment: Try with you mac ip address, and check if 80 port has open.

Comment: I tried with the ip address with no result, it keeps loading, where can I check if the port is open?

Comment: In your router settings. Check your routers manual for admin IP address, username/password, than search for Port Forwarding options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you get a **Forbidden** error, you should check permissions on your webserver. I've got a similar problem in my pc ( using Fedora ), and I solved it giving permissions to any user to execute files in my webserver, with a chmod like this:

```
chmod +x -R /path/to/webserver-files/
```

Hope it helps!